# Going back from other form

Tags: c#, visual-studio

```
    public string _FNAME = string.Empty;  //global variable
    public Form2(string FNAME) //parameter
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _rdbtnSpecial.Hide();
        _rdbtnSharing.Hide();

        _FNAME = FNAME;   // for data calling
```

I used that code so that I can get a data from Form 1 to Form 2 and now. I am having a hard time to go back from Form 3 to Form 2 with

```
Form2 _form2 = new Form2()
this.Show();
```

What should I add to that code so I can go back from Form 3 to form 2?
thank you :)

Comment: In `Form3`, you'll have to know the `FNAME` as well so you can pass it back to `Form2`

Comment: what do you mean sir? can you give me some example

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your question: Where is this Form3 you speak of? What do you mean by "go back to form 2"? Reopen a closed form? Notice that Form2 requires a string parameter and you do not supply one when you try to create it. What do you mean by "having a hard time"? Does not compile, does not run correctly?

Comment: uhmm to put it simply i have a a booking system where form2 functions the booking capabilities and form3 where the loading will initiate.. when form3 is at 100% it will go back.

Comment: Pass the FNAME to form3 and from form3 pass it back to form2. You have the code to pass from form1 to form2 you can use the same code for that.

Comment: i did that but the problem is in form 3 there is no FNAME variable or literally in that form nothin is in their but a loading bar and 1 button

Answer (score 0):

I think I found your issue. It's a simple typo.

Replace

```
Form2 _form2 = new Form2();
this.Show();
```

With

```
Form2 _form2 = new Form2();
_form2.Show();
```

If you want to restore the FNAME as well, comment below and I'll explain that as well.

Comment: I did this but still there is a red mark on the new Form2();

Comment: Try `new Form2("");`

Comment: I also want to restore the FNAME

Comment: You'll then have to pass the FNAME to form 3 with `new Form3(FNAME)` and then instead of `new Form2("");` in Form3, use `new Form2(FNAME)`. This way, you pass FNAME to Form3 and then back to Form2, or saying it easier, you restored FNAME

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use the `ShowDialog` function. You can use it like this:

Form2:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var loadingScreen = new Form3())
        {
            var formResult = loadingScreen.ShowDialog();
            if (formResult == DialogResult.Cancel)
            {
                // form3 failed
            }
            else if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                // form3 completed
            }

            loadingScreen.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Now inside Form3 you can create a method that returns whatever you want:

```
pubilc partial class Form3 : Form
{
    //.. other code

    public string loadMethod()
    {
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK; // DialogResult.Cancel if failed
    }
}
```

Comment: actually sir in form3 there is nothin to return because it is just a loading screen

Comment: Ah sorry my mistake. I've updated the code examples accordingly.